# Is the Liquidlogic Remix good for starting in whitewater kayaking?

Tags: kayaks

Would the Liquidlogic Remix be a good first whitewater kayak? How would it measure up to similar more modern kayaks like the Dagger Phantom or Jackson Nirvana?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this SE. I think we would need to know your skill level (i.e. what grade of rapid you are comfortable shooting) and what kayaks you have tried out. I suspect there'll be no "one" answer to this - you should try some and see what you like rather than taking advice off the internet. Your local white-water club should have some loaners to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a "right" answer here. Some people will say the Remix is a great beginner kayak. Others will say it is terrible.

It's a good creek boat design despite it's age. It's not as fast as a Phantom/Nirvana/any other race inspired creek boat, but it's fairly stable and decently fun. And while comfort is a bit individual, I found it comfortable when I was in one for a couple weeks straight. If you want a creek boat it probably isn't a bad choice so long as you fit in it, and you are getting the correct size for your weight. People I know who own remixes tend to love them.

The bigger question is probably whether or not a creek boat is what you want to learn in. This is where people disagree. Some say it's great because it is stable and lets you get comfortable on the water faster. Other's say it's terrible because it is too forgiving and you develop bad habits. I'm more in the 2nd camp personally, but at the same time the best boat for a beginner is the one you have on the water. There are very few truly "bad" beginner boats out there (and the remix isn't one of them). If you found one at a good price and it's comfortable to sit in then you could certainly do a whole lot worse.

In short, it's at worst a fine choice. At best it's a great choice. I think hard to call it a terrible choice. Depends a bit who you ask.